# Reading from multiple S3 Buckets in Spark

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

I have a spark application running on a Yarn cluster that needs to read files from multiple buckets on an S3-compatible object store, each bucket having its own set of credentials.

According to [hadoop documentation](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/bk_cloud-data-access/content/s3-auth-per-bukcet.html) it should be possible to specify credentials for multiple buckets by setting configuration of the form `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.<bucket-name>.access.key=<access-key>` in the active `SparkSession` but that has not worked for me in practice.

An example that according to the documentation, I believe should work:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}

case class BucketCredential(bucketName: String, accessKey: String, secretKey: String)

object TestMultiBucketReadWrite {

  val credentials: Seq[BucketCredential] = Seq(
    BucketCredential("bucket.1", "access.key.1", "secret.key.1"),
    BucketCredential("bucket.2", "access.key.2", "secret.key.2")

  )

  def addCredentials(sparkBuilder: SparkSession.Builder, credentials: Seq[BucketCredential]): SparkSession.Builder = {
    var sBuilder = sparkBuilder
    for (credential <- credentials) {
      sBuilder = sBuilder
        .config(s"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.${credential.bucketName}.access.key", credential.accessKey)
        .config(s"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.${credential.bucketName}.secret.key", credential.secretKey)
    }
    sBuilder
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = addCredentials(SparkSession.builder(), credentials)
      .appName("Test MultiBucket Credentials")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val dummyDF = Seq(1,2,3,4,5).toDS()

    println("Testing multi write...")
    credentials.foreach(credential => {
      val bucket = credential.bucketName
      dummyDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json(s"s3a://$bucket/test.json")
    })

    println("Testing multi read...")
    credentials.foreach(credential => {
      val bucket = credential.bucketName
      val df = spark.read.json(s"s3a://$bucket/test.json").as[Long]
      println(df.collect())
    })
  }

}
```

However, when submitted the job fails with the following error:

```sh
Testing multi write...
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: null, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden, S3 Extended Request ID: null
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:798)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:421)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:976)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:956)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1426)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.json(DataFrameWriter.scala:545)
```

The job does succeed when I instead set the `fs.s3a.access.key` and `fs.s3a.secret.key` settings sequentially but that involves sequential reads/writes:

```scala
    //...
    println("Testing multi write...")
    credentials.foreach(credential => {
      val bucket = credential.bucketName
      spark.conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", credential.accessKey)
      spark.conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", credential.secretKey)
      dummyDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json(s"s3a://$bucket/test.json")
    })

    println("Testing multi read...")
    credentials.foreach(credential => {
      val bucket = credential.bucketName
      spark.conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", credential.accessKey)
      spark.conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", credential.secretKey)
      val df = spark.read.json(s"s3a://$bucket/test.json").as[Long]
      println(df.collect())
    })
    //...
```

Comment: What version of Spark, AWS lib ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this feature only works for hadoop-aws>=2.8.0.

Answer (score -1):

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403,
>   AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: null, AWS Error Code: null,
>   AWS Error Message: Forbidden, S3 Extended Request ID: null

403 Forbidden means understood the request and cant serve....

***s3 account does not have access permission for one of your mutliple bucket[s].***
pls check again...

One of the reason might be proxy issue...

AWS uses http proxy to connect to aws cluster. I hope those proxy settings are right
define these sample variables in your shell script,

```
 SPARK_DRIVER_JAVA_OPTS="
        -Dhttp.proxyHost=${PROXY_HOST}
        -Dhttp.proxyPort=${PROXY_PORT}
        -Dhttps.proxyHost=${PROXY_HOST}
        -Dhttps.proxyPort=${PROXY_PORT}
        $SPARK_DRIVER_JAVA_OPTS"

    SPARK_EXECUTOR_JAVA_OPTS="
        -Dhttp.proxyHost=${PROXY_HOST}
        -Dhttp.proxyPort=${PROXY_PORT}
        -Dhttps.proxyHost=${PROXY_HOST}
        -Dhttps.proxyPort=${PROXY_PORT}
        $SPARK_EXECUTOR_JAVA_OPTS"

    SPARK_OPTS="
        --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.proxy.host=${PROXY_HOST}
        --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.proxy.port=${PROXY_PORT}
        $SPARK_OPTS"
```

spark submit would look like...

```
  spark-submit \
      --executor-cores $SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES \
      --executor-memory $SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY \
      --driver-memory $SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY \
      --driver-java-options "$SPARK_DRIVER_JAVA_OPTS" \
      --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="$SPARK_EXECUTOR_JAVA_OPTS" \
      --master $SPARK_MASTER \
      --class $APP_MAIN \
      $SPARK_OPTS \
      $APP_JAR "$@"
```

Note : AFAIK, if you have s3 access to AWS EMR no need to set access keys every time since it will be implicit

Comment: The spark application will not be running on AWS itself. Proxy settings are all correct, when I setup the credentials for a bucket using `fs.s3a.access.key=<access-key>` and `fs.s3a.secret.key=<secret-key>` I'm able to connect to __a__ bucket, however I cannot use this approach to connect to multiple buckets concurrently as per my question.

Comment: ddi you find any solution for this ?